# Input string was not in a correct format var row = db.QuerySingle(sqlSelect, id);

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code:

```
@{
var id = UrlData[0];
if (id.IsEmpty()){
    Response.Redirect(@Href("~/surveydata"));
}

var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");

if (IsPost){
    var sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM PatientSurvey WHERE ID=@0";
    db.Execute(sqlDelete, id);
    Response.Redirect("~/surveydata");
}

var sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM PatientSurvey WHERE ID=@0";
var row = db.QuerySingle(sqlSelect, id);
}

<p>Are we sure we want to delete the following record? @id</p>
<p>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="button" onclick="document.location.href='surveydata.cshtml';"   value="Cancel" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
</p>
```

Lines:

> Line 18:     var sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM PatientSurvey WHERE ID=@0";
>   Line 19:     var row = db.QuerySingle(sqlSelect, id);
>
> Stack Trace:
>   [FormatException: 0 : surveydata.cshtml - Input string was not in a correct format.]
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.FillParameterDataBindings(Boolean verifyValue) +1244
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options) +569
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +19
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() +12
>   WebMatrix.Data.d__0.MoveNext() +152
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +164
>
>   WebMatrix.Data.Database.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] args) +103
>
>   ASP._Page_delete_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Matt\Documents\My Web Sites\Scott New PTSSM\delete.cshtml:19
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors) +69
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +151
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext) +114

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to leave spaces like so:

```
var sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM PatientSurvey WHERE ID = @0";
```

Cheers